# MongoDB lookup expression with nearSphere criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

I have a scenario where I have to join my restaurants and zips collection based on their location.

**Restaurants**

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cba2486c522cafdb059deb"),
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -74.138492,
            40.631136
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "name" : "Indian Oven"
}]
```

**Zips**

```
[{
    "_id" : "99950",
    "city" : "KETCHIKAN",
    "loc" : [
        -133.18479,
        55.942471
    ],
    "pop" : 422,
    "state" : "AK"
}]
```

Now I have to join these two collection based nearSphere geo spatial queries. What criteria should I have to use in $lookup pipeline.

What I tried is

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "zips",
                let: { location: "$location" },
                pipeline: [{
                    $match: {
                        'loc': { $nearSphere: '$$location' }
                    }
                }],
                as: "t"
            }
    }
]);
```

but this is not working.

Need help